Retrieving data from outside current subdomain in integration event handler
In our application, which among other things handles vehicle assessment orders, we want to separate all notifications (email/sms) sent from the system to a separate subdomain (clean architecture-ish). The notifications should be sent based on given domain events which in turn are mapped into system wide integration events.
When an assessment/order is booked, an AssessmentCreated domain event is published. This contains some data such as assessment id and station id (the station where the vehicle assessment should be performed). The Assessment entity does however not have knowledge of station data such as station name or address (hence it can not be added to the event payload).
In the application layer of assessment, the domain event is mapped into an AssessmentCreatedIntegrationEvent
The Station is it's own aggregate (which is referenced to from assessment and other aggregates)
The idea is that an event handler in the Notifications subdomain acts on the AssessmentCreatedIntegrationEvent and subsequently generates an email notification which is sent to the customer.
However, the notification we want to send (order confirmation), should amongst other things contain the station name and address, which the event does not contain.
But what are the possible ways of retrieving this without making too tight connections?
Is it a valid approach to access "GetStationByIDQuery" in Station application layer from Notifications application layer? Or could the Notification infrastructure implement its own NotificationsStationRepository which retrieves it's own NotificationStation entity with the station data which is relevant for notification subdomain?
The structure is currently something like this:
Assessment

Domain

Assessment entity


Application
Infrastructure

Station

Domain

Station entity


Application
Infrastructure

Notifications

Domain
Application

SendBookingConfirmationNotificationWhenAssessmentIsCreated


Infrastructure

